# Making a phone call not directly

Tags: android, phone-call

To make a phone call, I just click on a button and I'm directly making the phone call. But I want to change that.

What I want, it's when I click on the button, I move to the composer like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOE6M.png).
Then, I can confirm ou not the call phone.

Please, can you helpe me ? This is my actual code

```
    buttonCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view){
                Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" 1234567));    
                startActivity(call);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` or `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL`.

From [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

> ACTION_VIEW tel:123 -- Display the phone dialer with the given number filled in.
>
> ACTION_DIAL tel:123 -- Display the phone dialer with the given number filled in.

Comment: Should I add other permission in the Manifest.xml please ?

Comment: I don't see if you need to add permission for this. Have you try it?

Comment: You can use Intent.ACTION_DIAL instead of Intent.ACTION_CALL and get the same permission in manifest.

Comment: @AndrewT. , can you please suggest ACTION_VIEW or ACTION_DIAL which one is better for showing the dialpad with filled number

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to show the dialpad with the phone no.
Use this in onClick

```
Intent dial = new Intent();
dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
startActivity(dial);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
```